# Best way to check macro definitions stored in a configuration file

Tags: c, kernel-module

I'm developing a driver that allows the user to define your settings in a .h file.

What would be the best way to check those settings?

Currently there is a function that checks these values and stores them in an array. Would it be correct to put in that function things like ...?

```
#ifndef MACRO
  #error "Error: ...."
#endif
```

Thanks all!

Comment: You want to check if the header is included?

Comment: @IdeaHat No, I want to check if the user has not forgotten to include any of the required values.

Comment: A better solution is to not make that possible. If a header file has must-have dependencies, it should include the other header file. Though I would suspect that much of your must-have dependencies aren't really must-have.

Comment: @IdeaHat Any other good alternative for a user can define settings? Thanks